# C : Write multiple arrays with one function.

Tags: c, function, arduino, arguments, arduino-uno

I am working on a program that will write a question and then four answers to the serial monitor of an arduino. 
I have my strings defined as such:

```
   char question[] = "Question here";
   char answ_A[] = "answer1";
   char answ_B[] = "answer2";
   char answ_C[] = "answer3";
   char answ_D[] = "answer4";
```

I would like to write one print function and pass the array name to it. Like this:

```
void printarray(arrayname){
    int arraysize = (sizeof(arrayname) / sizeof(char));
    //insert loop to print array element by element
    }
```

Is there a way to pass the array's name as a parameter? I want to be able to call it as such

```
printarray(question[]);
```

Comment: why not creating an array of string and put question and its answers in that array ?

Comment: @Meninx I may end up just doing that. I'd like to see if there is a way to do it this way however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own structure (some kind of dictionary), but C doesn't have any facility for referencing variables by name where the name isn't known at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass a single-dimension array as an argument in a function, you would have to declare function formal parameter.

/* pass pointer to the array as an argument */

```
printArray( question) ;

void printArray(char question[])
{
//process
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you're asking for; do you want one function to print both the question and all four answers in one operation?

If so, you could write something like the following:

```
char question[] = "Question here";
char answ_A[] = "answer1";
char answ_B[] = "answer2";
char answ_C[] = "answer3";
char answ_D[] = "answer4";

/**
 * Set up an array of pointers to char, where each
 * element will point to one of the above arrays
 */
const char *q_and_a[] = { question, answ_A, answ_B, answ_C, answ_D, NULL };

printQandA( q_and_a );
```

then your `printQandA` function would look something like this:

```
/**
 * Print the question and answers.  Use the pointer p to 
 * "walk" through the question and answer array.
 */
void printQandA( const char **question )
{
  const char **p = question; 

  /**
   * First element of the array is the question; print it
   * by itself
   */
  printf( "%s\n", *p++ );

  /**
   * Print the answers until we see the NULL element
   * in the array.
   */
   while ( *p )
     printf( "\t-%s\n", *p++ );
}
```

Comment: Or to mimic more the way he wants to use it, I think he could write `void printQandA( const char **question )
{
    int arraysize = (sizeof(question ) / sizeof(char*));` and then iterate...

Comment: @frarugi87: `sizeof question / sizeof (char *)` won't give him the number of elements in the array.

Comment: @frarugi87: because the `question` parameter is simply a pointer; `sizeof question` will return the size of the pointer object, not the size of the array it points to.  So `sizeof question / sizeof (char *)` will be equivalent to `sizeof (char **) / sizeof (char *)`.

Comment: @frarugi87: now, what *would* work is if he did `sizeof q_and_a / sizeof *q_and_a`, and passed that result as a separate parameter to `printQandA`.  Since `q_and_a` is an array expression, `sizeof q_and_a` will return the number of bytes in the whole array.

Comment: I thought that the `const` keyword behaved differently... Thank you for your explanation :)